# How to send form without clicking submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html

So here i have radio buttons. Each radio buttons corresponds to different parts. What i want to do is when the user click the radio button it will load the picture that needed without clicking the submit button.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <div class="customizeparts" style="width: 224px">
            <h3>CHOOSE YOUR PARTS</h3>
            <hr />
            <?php 
            if ($getmotorparttypes!=0){
                foreach($getmotorparttypes as $keymotorparttype=>$valuemotorparttype){
            ?>
            <a href="#" class="customizepartsbutton" style="width: 90%"><?php echo $valuemotorparttype["motorparttype_name"]; ?></a> 
            <div class="cls">
            </div>
                <?php 
                $currentrecord = current($getmotorset);
                $getmotorsets = $motorset->getmotorsetbymotortypeidnmotorparttypeid($currentrecord["motordata"]["motortype_id"], $valuemotorparttype["motorparttype_id"]);
                if ($getmotorsets!=0){
                    foreach($getmotorsets as $keyms=>$valuems){
                ?>
                <div class="upgrade">
                    <div class="upgrade-left" style="width: 65px;">
                        <input <?php echo ismotorsetselected($getmotorset,$valuems["motorpart_id"]); ?> name="<?php echo $valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorparttype_id"].",".$valuems["motortype_id"]; ?>"value="<?php echo $valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorpart_id"]; ?>" type="radio" /> <?php echo $valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorpart_id"]; ?>
                        <img alt="image" src="upload/image/<?php echo $valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorpart_image"]; ?>" width="60" height="auto" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="upgrade-right" style="width: 140px">

                        <?php echo $valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorpart_name"]; ?><br />
                        PHP. <?php echo number_format($valuems["motorpartdata"]["motorpart_price"],2); ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <?php 
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmitdesigncomb" value="CHOOSE UPGRADES" />
        </form>
```

Is this possible or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, but many who know javascript, but not PHP cannot help you.  If you included the generated javascript (what the browser actually sees and available in the browser with View/Source), then we could help also.

Comment: As @j08691 said, you need to use an Ajax function and use an event like onclick or onselect to trigger the function.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You'd not even necessarily need AJaX - you could just preload the parts list by dropping it out from PHP with `json_encode()` - maybe even mung it into a "JavaScript" file and include with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/motorparts.js.php"> </script>` then it would cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look into AJAX.  It's the only way you're going to be able to do this.  By utilizing AJAX you'll be able to do what you're in need of.

Of course, it could be done with just javascript as well (to the best of my knowledge).  If it's dynamic content coming from a database then ajax will be your best bet though.  It's not all that hard to learn and there are plenty of tutorials available online to get you up to speed quickly.

Otherwise we'll need to see any javascript you've written thus far to try and attempt this or it will be shooting in the dark.